# Animate Maze Solution Painting with Java Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, animation, paintcomponent, maze

I am working on a Computer Science Project and have been stumped by this problem for approaching 72 hours. I have Google'd, re-Google'd, and Google'd a third time. Somehow, I just cannot seem to get it to work. Basically, I have to paint a maze, and then animate the solution path. This is the painting code I have so far, painting the maze works just fine, I simply cannot get it to animate.

```
private class MazePanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        MazeApp.g = (Graphics2D) g;
        paintMaze();
    }
}
...
private static Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    private int space = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Point3d p = solutionSpaces.get(space);
        g.fillRect((int)p.x * spaceLength, (int)p.y * spaceWidth, spaceLength, spaceWidth); // g is static reference to Graphics2D, set from MazePanel
        mazePanel.repaint(); //mazePanel is instance
        space++;
    }
});
...
private void paintMaze()
{
    if (this.reader != null)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < this.reader.getWidth(); col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < this.reader.getLength(); row++)
            {
                MazeConstruct c = reader.check(row, col, floor);
                if (c == MazeConstruct.WALL)
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else if (c == MazeConstruct.ELEVATOR)
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                else if (c == MazeConstruct.START)
                    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                else if (c == MazeConstruct.FINISH)
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                else if (c == MazeConstruct.OPEN)
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                if (c != MazeConstruct.SOLUTION && c != MazeConstruct.TRAVERSED)
                    g.fillRect(row * spaceLength, col * spaceWidth, spaceLength, spaceWidth);
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawRect(row * spaceLength, col * spaceWidth, spaceLength, spaceWidth);
            }
        }
    }
    if (solving)
    {
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

The code provided will adequately paint the full solution instantly, but I need it to step through each individual space as an animation. Please help me. This is my absolute last resort! If I need to provide ANY additional information, please let me know. Also, *constructive* criticism is welcomed. Thank you so much.

[EDIT] I found a random question on here that stated a general point that a timer's tick (actionPerformed()) should only update the state of your data (e.g. move to next space) instead of actually painting, AND that Graphics g should not be held after paintComponent calls. I will use this new small pieces of information to solve my problem. Answers still welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem (correct me if not) you cant get the screen to update when you step through each individual space. In which such case you would use the repaint(); method.

Comment: I am calling repaint() inside the timer's actionPerformed method. Do you mean calling repaint() elsewhere? Care to elaborate?

Comment: sorry when I posted this reply, due to my poor internet connection, your code hadn't loaded yet and my reply was fully based on the text you gave us...

Comment: It seems like no matter what I place inside the MazePanel paintComponent() method OR the timer's actionPerformed() method, NOTHING inside the timer will be painted on to the panel. This problem is killing me.

Comment: Well im stumped also... (Im as novice as novice gets)

Answer (score 0):

Few things that you have to remember while rendering graphics `Component`:

1) `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` objects are not permanent, it is temporarily created when you call repaint(), you must not rely on the copy of `Graphics` object (like saving it as static variable). You must dispose it after using it.

2) Call all methods using `Graphics` object from inside `paintComponent()` method using only the copy of `Graphics` object passed to the paintComponent() method.

Here is the template you must use:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.draw...(...);
    g.fill...(...);
    yourMethod((Graphics2D)g);
    ....
    ....
}
private void yourMethod(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setPaint(..);
    g.draw...();
    ....
}
```

You are saving the Graphics object and using it outside paintComponent() that is not correct, and might result in undefined behaviour. You are calling `g.fillRect((int)p.x * spaceLength, (int)p.y * spaceWidth, spaceLength, spaceWidth);` with a saved instance of `g`!, which is a serious problem.

Another thing to remember is that repaint() method might not call paintComponent() if it is already being drawn.

The above template will work for your case. However, if you are really interested in very good performance (with lot of drawing being done) than you must use double buffering (i.e. draw to an image using separate thread and then put the image on screen at once).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not aware of the Graphics object's "scope." I am not too worried about performance, the "worst case" according to our prof. is a 25x25x10 which paints instantaneously for me. Would you mind elaborating some on the repaint() not calling paintComponent()? I thought that was what repaint did *specifically.*

Comment: I think the problem is that you are saving `Graphics` object. That is probably why `paintComponent()` is not being called. I think it will be called once at the begining, then `g` is not being released so it gets stuck. Pass `g` as an argument to paintMaze() method, something like `paintMaze(Graphics g)`. Remove the `static` definition of Graphics object.

Comment: So then how can I paint from the timer's actionPerformed, exactly? Since it is a method defined inside an ActionLstener, I cannot pass a reference to Graphics to it? Or would you recommend refactoring to where the timer only updates the data state (e.g. which maze cell to paint) and rewriting my paintMaze accordingly?

Comment: call `repaint()` from actionPerformed() method. And put the drawing code inside `paintComponent()` method, after the line  `super.paintComponent()`.

Comment: So I should not tell the actionPerformed() to fillRect(), correct?

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  ....  g.dispose();`  **Always** dispose of a `Graphics` object that your code explicitly creates.  **Never** dispose of a `Graphics` object that is ***passed*** to your code.

Comment: @NickAlexander I am sorry for my mistake. The dispose() method must not be called as the Graphics object is passed by the Swing.